# Equivalent forms for a product notation

Tags: statistics, inequality, proof-explanation, machine-learning

Context: See "2 Hoeffding’s Inequality" in :
http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture2.pdf

My particular question arises within 'section 2 Hoeffding's Inequality' is:
$$
e^{-tn\varepsilon }\prod_{i}^{}\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{tY_{i}}) = e^{-tn\varepsilon }(\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{tY_{i}}))^{n}.
$$
I did not understand how the these two are equal.  I think I understand now, but I want some confirmation...if Y1 = frequency of heads in 3 coin flips, Y2 = frequency of heads in 2 coin flips...

$$Y_{1}\neq Y_{2}$$

BUT, the expection$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(Y_{1})=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(Y_{2})=.5$$ and so,

$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{tY_{1}})=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{tY_{2}})?$$
It's the equal expectations that allows the removal of product notation and use the exponent 'n'.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

It is due to the expectations are equal.$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{tY_{1}})=\ldots  = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{tY_{n}})$$

I prefer to remove the $i$ on the right hand side though and replace it with a particular index. 
$$
e^{-tn\varepsilon }\prod_{i}^{}\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{tY_{i}}) = e^{-tn\varepsilon }(\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{tY_{1}}))^{n}.
$$